# Observium and SNMP

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, system-monitoring, observium

I have Observium installed but I can't seem to get the unix-agent to get MySQL, Apache and other statistics.

I have the unix-agent enabled under the Poller Modules. I have also tested and ensured the server-status page could be reached.

```
ls -la /usr/lib/observium_agent/local
total 76
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 11 12:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jul 10 23:13 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2910 Jul 11 12:43 apache
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   372 Jul 11 12:43 hddtemp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51594 Jul 11 12:43 mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    64 Jul 11 12:45 mysql.cnf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   116 Jul 11 12:44 temperature
```

and

```
ls -la /usr/bin/observium_agent
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13584 Jul 11 12:54 /usr/bin/observium_agent
```

and

Comment: Which OS distribution/version?

Comment: Debian 7. I'm still on the host box. But I'll begin playing with RedHats later on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Had to setup xinetd. Their documentation really has poor context.

Comment: Observium developers don't guarantee any real support for RHEL/CentOS-like operating systems.

Comment: Ditto for FreeBSD, though there's an ancient version in ports. It seems as if only Debian/Ubuntu is really well supported OS.